# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglscblas

Tags: gcc, rstudio, gsl

See the thing is, there is no such thing as a file to link to named glscblas  because that's a typo.

Here's an example of the problem when Rstudio calls gcc:

```
install.packages('devtools')
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgsl -lglscblas -o openssl.so aes.o base64.o bignum.o cert.o compatibility.o diffie.o envelope.o error.o hash.o info.o keygen.o keys.o onload.o openssh.o password.o pem.o pkcs12.o pkcs7.o rand.o rsa.o signing.o ssl.o stream.o write.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglscblas
```

Where could the filename typo be hiding, that is, what file holds the filename that feeds -l parameters to gcc when calling install.packages in Rstudio?  Rstudio invokes gcc with some wrong linker parameter that's obviously a typo for gnu scientific library "gslcblas" -- notice the gls / gsl character ordering mixup.  **It's harming the build anytime I run the command install.packages when it depends on the gnu scientific library, which is a lot of packages.** It's crippling my Rstudio system.  Installing today's latest Rstudio did not fix it.  I can't seem to find the file that has the typo.  Can anyone help me find the file containing the typo? thank you so much for helping.  The RStudio forums were unresponsive, so I'm here now.

Rstudio server, Ubuntu 16.04, gcc. Additionally:

```
ga@ga-HP-Z820:~/Downloads$ ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR | tr -s ' ;' \\012
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64")
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib")
ga@ga-HP-Z820:~/Downloads$ gcc -print-search-dirs | sed '/^lib/b 1;d;:1;s,/[^/.][^/]*/\.\./,/,;t 1;s,:[^=]*=,:;,;s,;,;  ,g' | tr \; \\012
libraries:
  /usr/lib/nvidia-current/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/nvidia-current/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/lib/:./x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:./x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/nvidia-current/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/nvidia-current/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/lib/:./x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:./x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/:/usr/lib/nvidia-current/:./:/usr/lib/nvidia-current/:./:/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/:/lib/:/usr/lib/
```

Comment: Heh, I was going to say "You're not alone", but then I noticed this is also you: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115007043227-Fix-incorrect-global-default-linker-path-used-by-install-packages-in-rstudio-.  Did Kevin's suggestions there not provide any help?